# Make two apps communicate with each other using same signature

Tags: android, security, android-permissions

I have App A that has defined a permission with protection level as signature. This app starts a service that belongs to App B. It calls startService(intent) repeatedly (only the intent class name is defined to call the service).

I need to ensure that only App B receives the onStartCommand() and not other rogue apps (if someone tries to reverse engineer and create a service with same name etc). Do i define the same permission even in App B's manifest?

```
<permission
    android:name="my.android.permissions.MY_PERM"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="my.android.permissions.MY_PERM" />
```

This permission is already defined in App A's manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines into app B's manifest

```
<permission
    android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="my.android.permissions.MY_PERM"/>

<uses-permission android:name="my.android.permissions.MY_PERM" />

<!-- define an activity which can only be started through internal code -->
<service android:name="..."
          android:permission="my.android.permissions.MY_PERM" >
    ...
</service>
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="my.android.permissions.MY_PERM" />
```

into app A's manifest

Comment: There is no need to define permission in service too in this case. Look at Android docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#prmsn  "If this attribute is not set, the permission set by the <application> element's permission attribute applies to the service. If neither attribute is set, the service is not protected by a permission.

For more information on permissions, see the Permissions section in the introduction and a separate document, Security and Permissions."